# error when merge using hibernate 3 and ojdbc 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, jboss-eap-7

I get an error when I save my entity using the `merge()` method from `EntityManager`. This issue happens when I use Hibernate 3 combined with `ojdbc7 12.1.0.2.0 JDBC 4.1`, but if I change to `ojdbc6 11.2.0.3.0 JDBC 4.0` this error will disappear. Can anyone help to resolve my problem, because I need to use `ojdbc7`.

```
>[2017-03-30 14:52:42.184]: ERROR - TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(408) | Application exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.mycomp.casa.persistence.model.CustomerAccountOpening#554]; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.mycomp.casa.persistence.model.CustomerAccountOpening#554]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:404)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.mycomp.casa.persistence.model.CustomerAccountOpening#554]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:695)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor915.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.merge(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.mycomp.casa.persistence.model.CustomerAccountOpening#554]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2041)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.mergeTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:851)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:686)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkException(WrappedConnection.java:1972)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.checkException(WrappedStatement.java:1446)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.checkException(WrappedResultSet.java:5986)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.next(WrappedResultSet.java:2693)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:825)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    ... 167 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 128
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.readBitVector(T4CTTIrxd.java:135)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIrxh.unmarshalV10(T4C8TTIrxh.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXH(T4C8Oall.java:678)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1066)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1015)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:979)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:579)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.next(WrappedResultSet.java:2689)
    ... 170 more
```

Comment: What is your Oracle database server version?

Comment: Also why do you "need to use ojdbc7"?

Comment: my oracle version is12 c

Comment: coz company that buy my apps , use ojdbc7 as the company standardization

Comment: There's another question (looks like a duplicate) with an interesting [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43502973/851811). Voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem using the 12.1.0.2 driver with an Oracle 10g database. It happens apparently when the driver is performing a fetch - querying the database for more rows while scrolling through a ResultSet.

Looks like a nasty bug in the driver as @MarkRotteveel pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112673/error-when-merge-using-hibernate-3-and-ojdbc-7#comment73324539_43113813).

Incrementing the `fetchSize` property worked well as a temporary workaround to avoid the issue, forcing the driver to retrieve all results at once with no data left to fetch, but it is not a long-term solution and may have a large negative impact on performance/memory depending on the size and amount of data the query is retrieving.

If you're using Hibernate, try to identify the query that is raising the exception (use for instance `hibernate.show_sql`), check how many rows does it return and adjust the [`hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-jdbc-properties) property accordingly.

> A non-zero value determines the JDBC fetch size (calls [Statement.setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-)).

Or try using a different version of the driver. This exception didn't happen with 12.1.0.1 if I remember correctly.

Comment: I tried and the same exception occurrs both on ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 drivers.

Comment: @MichałStochmal [The only difference between ojdbc6 and ojdbc7 should be JVM compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31931251/851811) (compiled with JDK6 or 7). If it's the same driver version they should be raising the same exception. Try to find the real driver version looking at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF inside the jar, downloading a newer driver version from oracle.com should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle 12c, try using Oracle12cDialect for the dialect.

Comment: which is not available in hibernate 3 :) @user3767527, you'll have to upgrade hibernate, or backport the Dialect from hibernate 5 to hibernate 3, but it seems the contract of `Dialect` to have changed a lot between those 2 major versions

Comment: The error indicates a low-level error in the protocol implementation in the Oracle JDBC driver: I'd be surprised if that is due to the Hibernate dialect.