# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.readBitVector(T4CTTIrxd.java:135)

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

Trying to access collection using lazy loading and facing below issue, I'm not able to figure out what is the cause of this issue.

I am using Hibernate3 with Spring and Driver 12.1.0.2 oracle 11.2.0.4.0. Below is the error log.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.readBitVector(T4CTTIrxd.java:135)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIrxh.unmarshalV10(T4C8TTIrxh.java:123)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRXH(T4C8Oall.java:678)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1066)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.fetchMoreRows(OracleStatement.java:3716)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.fetchMoreRows(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:1015)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.absoluteInternal(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:979)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.next(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:579)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.next(WSJdbcResultSet.java:3120)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:697)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1994)
     at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
     at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
     at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:63)
     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
     at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:344)
     at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:86)
     at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:163)
     at org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.select(CollectionUtils.java:515)
     at com.cmt.acq.service.AcqCampaignService.getGrid(AcqCampaignService.java:1245)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
     at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:126)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:50)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.getGrid(Unknown Source)
     at com.cmt.acq.action.AcqManageCampaignAction.generateXMLResponse(AcqManageCampaignAction.java:1073)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly due to row compression. The database recognizes sequential duplicate column values and instead of sending the value again just sends "ditto" conceptually. So this problem is highly dependent on the data returned. Unless the query contains ORDER BY even repeat executions of a single query on a single database can return the rows in a different order so this problem can be difficult to reproduce.

There have been several patches to this code in recent releases. I vaguely recall seeing this problem but I can't find a bug for it. Still the code has changed a lot recently so I suggest trying 12.2.0.1.0 which is available on [Oracle Maven](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/entry/oracle_maven_repository_instructions_for). If it reproduces with 12.2.0.1.0 please file a bug.

Comment: We have used multiple one to one mapping for our object and whiling fetching the cell throwing this exception, Also I checked the sql query, its too big with lots of left outer join 
<one-to-one name="acqCommonField" class="com.cmt.acq.vo.AcqCommonField" cascade="all" ></one-to-one>

Comment: Thanks for providing details Douglas, makes sense. Had a hard time with this one. We may consider upgrading to 12.2.0.1.0.

Comment: Upgrading the driver fixed this issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem using the 12.1.0.2 driver with an Oracle 10g database. It happens apparently when the driver is performing a fetch - querying the database for more rows while scrolling through a ResultSet.

Looks like a nasty bug in the driver.

Incrementing the `fetchSize` property worked well as a temporary workaround to avoid the issue, forcing the driver to retrieve all results at once with no data left to fetch, but it is not a long-term solution and may have a large negative impact on performance/memory depending on the size and amount of data the query is retrieving.

If you're using Hibernate, try to identify the query that is raising the exception (use for instance `hibernate.show_sql`), check how many rows does it return and adjust the [`hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-jdbc-properties) property accordingly.

> A non-zero value determines the JDBC fetch size (calls [Statement.setFetchSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize-int-)).

Or try using a different version of the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your response Xavi López, I have two environment one for development and other for test, the problem is all is working fine in testing environment but the same code is braking on testing environment.
I am using hibernate + spring

Comment: Development working fine but on testing environment the same code is breaking.

Comment: It must have something to do with a specific query and the data it's returning in your testing environment. According to what I observed in my situation, it must be returning a number of rows > your configured batch size. In development there must be less data so the driver doesn't need to fetch more rows while iterating through the resultset, avoiding the bug. Increment that with the `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` property, or switch to another version of the Oracle Driver.

Comment: If I connect my testing database from development environment it's working fine.

Comment: And are you certain your development environment is using exactly the same oracle driver version as in your testing environment?

Comment: Below is the sql query that causing the issue also we have used multiple one to one in the code because of that is trying to fatch all the records

Comment: We have used multiple one to one mapping for our object and whiling fetching the cell throwing this exception, Also I checked the sql query, its too big with lots of left outer join 
<one-to-one name="acqCommonField" class="com.cmt.acq.vo.AcqCommonField" cascade="all" ></one-to-one>