# Oracle jdbc execute throw "AarrayIndexoutofBoundsException at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CITIrxdsBitset.set"

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to through the oracle metadata table "ALL_OBJECTS" to query table info in my application, but everytime execute to `"rs.next()"` it throw the `AarrayIndexoutofBoundsException`, and I am pretty sure my code don't have that kind issue, it stuck me long for long time.

The oracle version is `"11.2"` and spring boot version is `"2.3.12"`.

I try a lot of ojdbc driver like: `"ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar"`, `"ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar"` and `"ojdbc8-19"` etc . also try to set Statement `"setFetchSize()"` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```java
public void demo() {
        List<Map<String, String>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS O WHERE O.OWNER = 'LINEWELL' AND O.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW')";
        BasicDataSource datasource; // initial datasource
        try (
                Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)
        ) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("TableCatalog", rs.getString("OWNER"));
                map.put("TableSchema", rs.getString("OWNER"));
                map.put("TableName", rs.getString("OBJECT_NAME"));
                map.put("TableType", rs.getString("OBJECT_TYPE"));
                map.put("LastModifyTime", rs.getString("LAST_DDL_TIME"));
                resultList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(resultList.size());
    }
```

Here is full stack infomation, The "MyTest.java:88" refer to "new HashMap<>()".

```
Caused by:java.lang.ArrayIndexoutofBoundsException:3
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxdsBitset.set (T4CTTIExd.java:1593)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4CTTIrxd.readBitVector (T4CTTIrxd.java:135)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4C8TTIrxh.unmazshalVl0 (T4C8TTIrxh.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4C80all.readRX(4C80all.java:693)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive (T4CTTIfun.java:529)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC (T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4C80all.doOALL (T4C80all.java:612)
    at oracle.jdbe.driver.T4CStatement.dooal18 (T4CStatement.java:213)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.fetch (T4CStatement.java:1009)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.Oraclestatement.fetchMozeRovs (OracleStatement.java:3353)
    at oracie.jdbc.driver.InsensitivescrollableResultset.fetchMoreRows (InsensitiveScrollableResuleset.java:736)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensicivescrollableResultset.absoluteInternal (InsensitivescrollableResultset.java:692)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitivesczollableResultset.next (InsensitiveScrollableResultset.java:406)
    at org.apache.commons.dbep2.DelegatingResulcset.next (DelegatingResultsec.dava:1160)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingResultset.next (DelegatingResultset.java:1160)
    at com.example.MyTest.demo(MyTest.java88）
```

Comment: Don't know if it would cause the error but you use "OWNER" twice with the getString(...) method.

Comment: @camickr table "ALL_OBJECTS " query result have cloumn "OWNER", it work for my anther oracle database, only this one will throw the exception.

Comment: @Hulk before the stack it also have the log info from the method caller, the demo that I provide is extract from my application, and I am pretty sure the exception is from there.

Comment: @camickr - The exception is in the `next` call itself.   Hulk - that looks like the full exception to me.

Comment: This looks rather like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265593.  The diagnosis (from an SO user who is an Oracle engineer) was "bug in Oracle's driver".  I suggest asking on Oracle's DB forums (which I can't access) or raising an Oracle support request / bug report.

Comment: @StephenC I see the link you post and try it but doesn't work for me, I will go to Oracle's forums to see what I can find, thanks.